# How do you quit an application using PyWebIO?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use [PyWebIO](https://github.com/pywebio/PyWebIO) to develop a desktop application. I can't figure out a very basic thing: if you use `start_server`, how do you quit the application from the web interface? Closing the application web browser window does not cause the overall application to exit. I'd like to provide the user with a quit/exit button, but can't figure out how to cause the server to exit cleanly on command. There is no explanation of this in the documentation as far as I can find, and there is no `stop` or quit action in PyWebIO. Telling the user to ^C the application from the command line is obviously undesirable.

How do other developers using PyWebIO for applications handle this?

Comment: Regarding closing web browser window: https://pywebio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#close-of-session (my apologies if you are already way ahead).

Comment: @PM77-1 Thank you. I read it, but can't figure out how to use it to accomplish deliberate quitting. It seems to need the use of the coroutine-based approach to PyWebIO, which I guess I could try to use instead of the default thread-based approach. So, maybe I need to try to restructure my application to use coroutines?

Answer (score 1):

PyWebIO provides a script mode to build local apps instead of web services.  In script mode, the program will exit after all the code has been executed. You just run your pywebio app function directly rather than passing it to `start_server()` to enable script mode.

A very simple pywebio app in script mode:

```py
from pywebio.input import input
from pywebio.output import put_text

name = input("what's your name?")
put_text("hello,", name)
```

Doc: https://pywebio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html#overview

Comment: Thanks; I actually do understand the difference between script mode and server mode in PyWebIO. The thing is, a desktop application shouldn't quit after it runs once; it stays until the user exits the application deliberately. Consequently, this seems to imply running in server mode, unless I really misunderstand PyWebIO.

Comment: Actually, both script mode and server mode can satisfy your case. If you run in script mode, you can put your bussiness logic to a `while` loop, and ask user whether to exit every loop. If you run in server mode, you can put a exit button and kill the server process (via `os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)`) when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following as exit statement within the main_task function that the server is running:

signal.raise_signal(signal.SIGINT)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).